# Calculating characteristic polynomials of matrices in GF(2)

Tags: matrices, finite-fields

How do you calculate a characteristic polynomial of a matrix in GF(2)? I understand the concept of characteristic polynomials in matrices using "regular" math with real numbers, but I'm a bit confused about how it works in GF(2).

Is there a relation between the characteristic polynomial and eigenvectors?

(I understood how to do this about ten years ago but it's been too long and I can't find my work from back then.)

---

*edit*: I guess the problem I'm having is that regular math matrices with integer values can have a characteristic polynomial with roots that are neither integer or real numbers, and those numbers make sense; I can't get my head around what happens in GF(2) algebra where similar cases occur. (e.g. characteristic polynomial = $x^3 + x + 1$)

Comment: Analogy: With real (or rational) matrices you may need to go to an extension field (a subfield of complex numbers) to find the eigenvalue and basis vectors for the eigenspaces. With matrices over a finite field the same thing happens. You often need to go to an extension field to find those objects. A difficulty comes from the fact that we don't have that comfy algebraic closure around here, and need to construct those extensions while we go, but that does not really change the rules of the eigenvalue game one bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of a matrix $M$ is always $\det (M - tI)$. Over a finite field, the coefficients of this polynomial lie in the same finite field but their roots lie in [algebraic extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension) of this finite field in general. A finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ has a unique such extension of order $n$ for each positive integer $n$, denoted $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ or, in your notation, $\text{GF}(p^n)$. Any reference on finite fields will explain this.

Comment: So you have to calculate the determinant?

Comment: @Jason: I'm not sure what you mean by "have to." You can also try computing the eigenvalues of $M$ but this is the easiest way to find out what their multiplicities are.

Comment: How do you find the eigenvalues of a matrix over $GF(2)$?