# How to find eigenvalues for mod 2 field?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Over $F_2=\{0,1\}$, a matrix $A$ is given as
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &1\\1&0
\end{bmatrix}.$$
I want to find its eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

$$\text{det}\left( A-\lambda I\right) = \text{det}\begin{bmatrix}
1-\lambda &1\\1&-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}=\lambda^2-\lambda-1=0.$$
However, either $\lambda = 0$ or $1$, $\text{det}(A-\lambda I)$ cannot be zero.

In this case, how to find the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors?

Comment: It has no eigenvalues over $\Bbb F_2$, but it has them over $\Bbb F_4$, the field of four elements.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670385/calculating-characteristic-polynomials-of-matrices-in-gf2